# having trouble understanding why this R syntax would work

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand why this R code does a certain transformation.

```
Df[,"cutoff"] = as.numeric(levels(Df[,"cutoff"]))[Df[,"cutoff"]]
```

Previously, Df[,"cutoff"] is a factor with 49 levels and now after this operation, it's a vector. I just don't understand this syntax at all. Is there an explanation behind what having as.numeric(levels(Df[,"cutoff"])) does to a factor?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/215487)?

Comment: That code is confusing, but if `cutoff` is "really" a numeric variable, then I think it's the same as `as.numeric(as.character(Df[,"cutoff"]))`, which is how you would convert a factor variable to numeric. Also, `Df[,"cutoff"]` is a vector either way, but before the operation its class is factor and after its class is numeric.

Comment: @Glassjawed, could you update your answer with what you you were trying to accomplish? Maybe the answer to that question would be more helpful.

Comment: To add to @eipi10 's response. Using the `.Primitive('[')` subset function seems to do something with the same effect as `as.numeric(Df[,"cutoff"])` , which interestedly requires an understanding of how R deals with `as.numeric(factor)` (with many explanations on SO).

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you get the numbers as factors, some R functions do not interpret those as numbers even though you see numbers. For example summary will count the number of cases instead the usual six numbers.

See:

```
Df=data.frame(cutoff=factor(rep(c(2:6),2)),y=runif(10,12,15))
str(Df)
summary(Df[,"cutoff"])
```

> ```
> 2 3 4 5 6 
> 2 2 2 2 2
> ```

```
#If you want the levels as numbers
Df[,"cutoff"] = as.numeric(levels(Df[,"cutoff"]))[Df[,"cutoff"]]
summary(Df[,"cutoff"])
```

> ```
>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>       2       3       4       4       5       6
> ```

Comment: You could get the same result with `as.numeric(as.character(Df[,"cutoff"]))`, but it is less efficient (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f)

Answer (score 0):

It's a vector of `NA`, if the factor was not a displayed numeric.

```
df <- data.frame(cutoff = letters[1:26])
as.numeric(levels(df[,"cutoff"]))[df[,"cutoff"]]
#  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

Let's break it down, this shows you the levels of the factor, returning a character string:

```
levels(df[,"cutoff"])
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" ...
```

This tries to convert a character string to numeric (which it can't, and therefore returns `NA`)

```
as.numeric(levels(df[,"cutoff"]))
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

Now, adding the last element `[df[,"cutoff"]]`, all this does is subset the result by the `factor` `df[,"cutoff"]`, but since every element is NA, you wouldn't see any difference. In practice this would likely change the order of the result in unexpected (read: useless) ways.

```
as.numeric(levels(df[,"cutoff"]))[df[,"cutoff"]]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Brandon, couldn't it be a numeric variable that somehow got converted to a factor? The OP's code would then convert it back to numeric, but `as.numeric(as.character(...))` is more straightforward.

Comment: Possible, but typically if it was "converted to factor somehow" that means there's a character in it somewhere, which means it would end up the same way.